# What is GAFM and GAFS in intel_gpu_top?

Tags: gpu, intel

I've gone through every PDF on [01 - Intel graphics for linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/hardware-specification-prms/2014-2015-intel-processors-based-broadwell-platform). I've Googled, DuckDuckGo'ed, and I have even Binged! But I cannot find any information regarding the acronyms at all.

Is there anyone out there who knows what they mean?